# How to fix multiple chrome shortcut to task bar

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, taskbar, links

Currently, I can only have 1 Chrome shortcut on my Windows 10 taskbar:

[image]
[image]
But I have several shortcuts with different links, which I would like to have pinned to the taskbar as well. Ex:

1. Link 1: https://google.com
2. Link 2: https://youtube.com

How can I have multiple links pinned to the taskbar?

Answer (score 1):

If AlexC solution isn't enough and you necessarily want this links directly accessible, you can use toolbar functionality (but only in Windows 10, it's deprecated on Windows 11).

1. Create 2 folders*
2. Create text files in one folder, each containing single line starting website in chrome

   START chrome.exe https://yourlinkhere
3. Change names of this files to .bat
4. Create shortcuts to this files in second folder, you can change their icons in properties
5. RMB on taskbar > toolbars > new toolbar
6. You'll have your shortcuts listed on right side of toolbar
7. When taskbar is unlocked you can get rid of text labels by RMBing on this toolbar handle

[image: PoC]

*You can omit all double folder contraption and just create toolbar from folder with batch files. But this way you would have all links with the same icon (cmd icon).

Comment: Just show a screenshot of two simultaneous chrome shortcuts in the same taskbar as requested in the op to prove this works. –

Comment: Right, that may be useful :) Screenshot added.

Comment: I think you've confused what I call "shortcuts in the task bar".
I put an image in the OP for you to understand better.

Comment: And these are "shortcuts in the task bar". "Not this" section of your image show tabs with opened programs. Toolbar contains shortcuts to start programs - you can click them, and they will start new chrome process with specific link.

Answer (score 0):

You can pin / unpin in chrome browser itself.
You dont have to pin it on windows taskbar.
Right click on the Tab and the pin.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the answer. I want to pint different chrome shortcuts in the windows taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it.

1. Open a new Chrome tab and navigate to the page you want. Then close it again.
2. Now on the Windows taskbar, right-click the Chrome icon. It should show a list of several sites which it considers your "most visited", and also show a list of several tabs you "recently closed".
3. Hover your mouse over the link showing the page you just closed, and a little pin icon will appear at the right. Click that pin and that link will now be pinned so it always appears at the top of the list when you right-click the Chrome icon.

[image: Steps 1-3]

Result, when you now right-click the Chrome icon again:

[image: Result]

Comment: Just show a screenshot of two simultaneous chrome shortcuts in the same taskbar as requested in the op to prove this works.

Answer (score -2):

Rogério, Go for it sir, add several as I myself have done.

Cheers, Jim

PS you may have to unlock the taskbar... r-click will show you where.

Comment: No, it's not working. Could you share some screenshot or video?